# Can I add a cordova plugin manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, plugins

I want to utilize [this](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake-detection) plugin in my phonegap/jquery-m application. Do I have to use the "install" method or can I simply download the js file and make a reference to it and the cordova.js file?

I would rather like to just refer to the js file, because it will be much easier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this javascript plugin manually, refer shake.js in html. if plugin is made with the help of native then u have to add plugin tag from plugin.xml to your plugin xml. These shake plugin is made in javascript so no need to add plugin tag in xml file.